# Data not post using .net core web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

this is my controller,when i tried to send data by postman using my api but sql database not updated but get http request work. my url was -http://localhost:51441/api/test/1 for getHTTP request  .IS THIS CORRECT?
i tried to post data by calling same url using postman POST method and raw data. please help me to solve this question,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApi4.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace WebApi4.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/test")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserDetailsTestController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserDetailContext _context;

        public UserDetailsTestController(UserDetailContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET api/UserDetails Table
        [HttpGet]

        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UserDetails>>> GetUserDetails()
        {

            return await _context.UserDetails.ToListAsync();
        }


        /// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // GET: api/UserDetails/3
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserDetails>> GetUserDetails(int id)
        {
            var userDetails = await _context.UserDetails.FindAsync(id);
            if (userDetails == null)

            {
                return NotFound();// NO NEED
            }
            return userDetails;
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutUserDetails(int id, UserDetails userDetails)
        {
            if (id != userDetails.UId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            _context.Entry(userDetails).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                //NEED
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!UserDetailsExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return NoContent();
        }


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



        // POST api/UserDetails
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserDetails>>PostUserDetails(UserDetails userDetails)
        {
            _context.UserDetails.Add(userDetails);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetUserDetails",new { id=userDetails.UId},userDetails);
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserDetails>> DeleteUserDetails(int id)
        {
            var userDetails = await _context.UserDetails.FindAsync(id);
            if(userDetails==null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            _context.UserDetails.Remove(userDetails);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return userDetails;
        }

        private bool UserDetailsExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.UserDetails.Any(e=>e.UId==id);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You can't seriously expect anyone to be able to answer this question in it's current state?

Comment: please help me now

Comment: It's still not possible to help. We have no idea how you are "sending data" to this action method. You haven't explained what "not respond" means. Please spend more than a few seconds writing your question or nobody can help.

Comment: sir please help me to correct my issues. i really apriciated if u can help me, I am a student and new to web api. i tried to send my full controller to stack overfloaw, every time i tried to send my question stackoverflow popup a error massage, please help me, this is a task realated to my internship,

Comment: Yes, but **what is the error message?** You may be new to web API, but you're not new to communicating with other people. Try and understand that we cannot help until you help us first.

Comment: Why on earth would I mention my email address?

Comment: i think now you can help me. thankyou

Comment: You are using async Tasks, but asynchronous code is pretty hard to deal with on a whim. Try to start with a minimal working code sample. Async code requires patience.

Comment: didnt get  what you are saying. i am new to c#, can u explain simply

Answer (score 0):

Use `[FromBody]` on your action like

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutUserDetails(int id, [FromBody]UserDetails userDetails)
```

Assume my `UserDetails` model is

```
public class UserDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int UId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

If you would like to do `Post` method, the url is `http://localhost:51441/api/test`, the postman needs to be configured like[image]

If you are doing `PUT` method, the url is `http://localhost:51441/api/test/1` .Postman needs to be configured like[image]

To get specific record, with `GET` method and the url is `http://localhost:51441/api/test/1` in your case.